# Не подключается модуль через Python c-api

Tags: c++, python

Есть Python код:

test.py:

```
from test2 import Say
Say()
```

test2.py:

```
def Say():
    print("Mew")
```

И есть c++ код:

```
#include <Python.h>
int main(){
Py_Initialize(); // инициализация интерпретатора
 PyObject *obj = Py_BuildValue("s", "test.py");
 FILE *file = _Py_fopen_obj(obj, "r+");
 if(file != NULL) {
     PyRun_SimpleFile(file, "test.py");
 }
Py_Finalize();
return 0;
}
```

Компилируется, но при попытке исполнения выдает следующие

```
File "test.py", line 1, in <module>
    from test2 import Say
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'test2'
```

Что я делаю не так, заранее спасибо!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Дело в том, что когда интерпретатор запускается из C-кода, в `sys.path` не добавляется текущая директория. Это можно сделать вручную, например так:

```
PyObject *sysPath = PySys_GetObject("path");
PyList_Append(sysPath, PyUnicode_FromString("."));
```